# Saving form data in the database using Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, struts2, struts-tags

When we click the save button it must save the form data in the database but its doing nothing.

Below is the code:

**`BodyDaywise.jsp`:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>    
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Day Wise</title>
</head>
<body align="center">
    <h1 align="center">Day Wise Form</h1>
        <html:form action="daywise" class="BodyDaywiseAction" method="POST" >
            
            LoginDate: <input type="date" name="LoginDate" displayformat="yyyy-mm-dd" label="Login Date(yyyy-mm-dd)"/><br><br>
            LoginTime:<input id="start" type="time"  name="LoginTime"/><br><br>
            LogoutTime:<input id="end" type="time"  name="LogoutTime"/><br><br>
            Task:<input type="textarea" name="Task" label="Task" cols="20" rows="5"/><br><br>
        
            <input type="submit" value="save" name="Save" onClick=""/>
            <button type="submit" value="Clear" name="clear">Clear</button>
            <input type="button" value="cancel" onClick="history.back();"/>
            </html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Action class: `BodyDaywiseAction.java`:**

```
package com.timesheet.action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.timesheet.db.DaywiseDBO;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
public class BodyDaywiseAction extends ActionSupport {
public BodyDaywiseAction()
{
}

private Date LoginDate;
private Time LoginTime;
private Time LogoutTime;
private String Task;

 
public Date getLoginDate() {
    return LoginDate;
}
    
public void setLoginDate(Date LoginDate) {
    this.LoginDate = LoginDate;
}

public Time getLoginTime() {
    return LoginTime;
}

public void setLoginTime(Time LoginTime) {
    this.LoginTime = LoginTime;
}

public Time getLogoutTime() {
    return LogoutTime;
}

public void setLogoutTime(Time LogoutTime) {
    this.LogoutTime = LogoutTime;
}

public String getTask() {
    return Task;
}

public void setTask(String Task) {
    this.Task = Task;
}

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 
             
 @Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    
     int i=DaywiseDBO.save(this);  
    if(i>0){  
    return "success";  
    }  
    return "error";  
}

@Override
public void validate() {
     if("".equals(getTask())){  
        addFieldError("Task", "Task must be filled !");
     }
}

}
```

**`DaywiseDBO.java`:**

```
package com.timesheet.db;
import com.timesheet.action.BodyDaywiseAction;
import com.timesheet.dbutil.DBUtil;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
public class DaywiseDBO {  

public static int save(BodyDaywiseAction BDA) throws Exception{  
int status=0;  
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
DBUtil util = null;

try{  
util = new DBUtil();
conn = util.getConnection();
ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into logintable values(?,?,?,?)");  
ps.setDate(1,BDA.getLoginDate());  
ps.setTime(2,BDA.getLoginTime());  
ps.setTime(3,BDA.getLogoutTime());  
ps.setString(4,BDA.getTask());  

status=ps.executeUpdate();  

}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();}  
return status;  
}  

}
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default, tiles-default">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles"
            class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>
    <action name="loginaction" class="com.timesheet.action.LoginAction" method="execute">
        <result name="input" >/Login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/bodydaywise.tiles</result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="daywise" class="com.timesheet.action.BodyDaywiseAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/bodydaywisesuccess.tiles</result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    </package>
  </struts>
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Dude... what is <html: ? That's a struts1 taglib, while you're importing struts2 ones... a complete mess here

Comment: You are missing `struts.xml`.

Comment: @Roman C please check now... I have edit Struts.xml

Comment: What does it means- **but its doing nothing**? r u getting some error? is the form submitted?

Comment: After click the save button it must save the data into database and it must go to success page. but instead its not even going an error page nor success page

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong date/time type in the action class. Struts2 have not build-in converters for `java.sql.*` types. The date/time values should be converted to date if you use `java.util.Date`. objects of this type can contain both date and time values.

```
import java.util.Date;

import java.sql.Time;
```

Change the getters and setters accordingly to return the required. You can also set the date object to `Calendar` and do some calculations, after that you can create a `Timestamp` object from the calendar. For example

```
user.setCreateDate(new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
```

sets the current **date & time** to the user object before the user is added to the database.

The example of using `PreparedStatement`: [JDBC PreparedStatement example – Insert a record](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/).

There's also an example to save *only* date part of the `Date`: [Insert date value in PreparedStatement](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-insert-date-value-in-preparedstatement/). (Don't use it, because it doesn't save a time portion of the `Date`).

Comment: Thank you Roman for the reply. I have changed it how you said 
but its still the same

Comment: Change the `html:` prefix to `s:` , the last is used in your taglib definition and qualify the Struts2 tags.

Comment: thank you @Roman sir... 
i did what u said but it should then this ERROR was showing 
'No result defined for action com.timesheet.action.BodyDaywiseAction and result input'    then i made change in the struts.xml file by adding result name as ' <result name="input" >/BodyDaywise.jsp</result>' it never added any data to the database.... i'm using tiles to do this project

Comment: You a re doing progress ;)

Comment: thank you sir @roman... can you please tell me why its not storing data in database.

Comment: first you need to check if you have a data, second if you have a database, and third you should `conn.commit()` your changes to it :)

Comment: yes @Roman sir I have data, database... and I also wrote Conn.commit() in DaywiseDBO.java... but still its not updating my table in Database

Comment: See the example that I have added to the answer.