# ResultSet is null on a specific table

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a database desktop client written on Java. I need to retrieve data from postgres, and no matter the connection (i mean database user role), no matter the host machine (i tried launching the code on different computers and database running on different containers) select query on the one specific table always returns null in ResultSet.

Here's the table:

```
Table "public.client"
          Column          |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 contact_phone            | character(11)     |           | not null | 
 status                   | character(11)     |           | not null | 
 money_spent              | real              |           | not null | 
 bonus                    | real              |           | not null | 
 client_name              | character varying |           | not null | 
 assigned_employee_number | character(11)     |           |          | 
 email                    | character varying |           |          |
```

Here's an example of Java query to this table:

```
List<Client> resultClientList = new ArrayList<>();
        try(PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT " +
                "contact_phone," +
                "status, " +
                "money_spent, " +
                "bonus, " +
                "client_name, " +
                "assigned_employee_number, " +
                "email " +
                "FROM client " +
                "WHERE assigned_employee_number IS NULL;")){
            resultClientList = executeClientQuery(stmt.getResultSet());
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            log.error("Error querying clients: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

And the method to extract data from resultset:

```
private List<Client> executeClientQuery(ResultSet resultSet){
        List<Client> resultClientList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(resultSet == null) return resultClientList;
        try{
            while(resultSet.next()){
                String contactPhone = resultSet.getString("contact_phone");
                String status = resultSet.getString("status");
                Double moneySpent = resultSet.getDouble("money_spent");
                Double bonus = resultSet.getDouble("bonus");
                String clientName = resultSet.getString("client_name");
                String assignedEmployeeNumber = resultSet.getString("assigned_employee_number");
                resultClientList.add(new Client(contactPhone, status, moneySpent, bonus, clientName, assignedEmployeeNumber));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            log.error("Error querying clients: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return resultClientList;
    }
```

At this point method `executeClientQuery` receives null in a ResultSet. I tried querying `SELECT * FROM client`, but that didn't help. I tried debugging JDBC code, but found nothing. No exception is thrown, just the ResultSet is null. Running this query in the database, however, returns correct data.

Connection is alive. Any other query on any other table returns correct ResultSet.

Comment: The null pointer exception should be thrown. But you caught the null value.

Comment: @RomanC – The NPE is not caught anywhere in the provided code …

Comment: The only way a `ResultSet` can be null is if you got an exception and returned null. Solution: either propagate the exception or test for null.

Comment: @tquadrat There's no any NPE in the code... Should be caught for sure. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32946450/573032) is an example of using JDBC statement.

Comment: @RomanC – you should never throw an NPE! And you should never caught an NPE in production code, as it indicates a significant design flaw! If something is expected to be `null` under some circumstances, you have to check for that condition. And if something *is* `null` although it *could not be* `null`, this should bubble up, to be seen.

Comment: @tquadrat In production, if you ever had a chance to work, you should know that NPE is a generally bug error. It should be fixed immediately. Because it is a runtime exception, and it stops the business processes. It must be prevented as much as possible to make a system stable and a bugfree. People who intentionally left the code with unchecked NPE make a dirty code with expected difficulties paid for maintenance and support.

Comment: @RomanC – ***Fixing*** an NPE and ***catching*** an NPE are two different things, as you should know if you ever had operated an application. Usually ***catching*** an NPE prevents it from being found, therefore from being fixed. Also ***checking for null*** and ***catching an NPE*** are different things – and what in hell is an "unchecked NPE"? Coming to the maintenance and support: caught NPEs are causing a lot of pain …

Comment: @tquadrat You will get a lot of pain if you left uncaught NPEs. If you also sit on the Telefone to accept calls from the users, then you explain them why the program is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [JavaDoc for `PreparedStatement::getResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet()) …

What you want to call is [`PreparedStatement::executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()):

```
List<Client> resultClientList = new ArrayList<>();
try( PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement( 
    """
    SELECT contact_phone,
           status, 
           money_spent,
           bonus,
           client_name,
           assigned_employee_number,
           email 
      FROM client 
      WHERE assigned_employee_number IS NULL;""" ) )
{
  resultClientList = executeClientQuery( stmt.executeQuery() );
}
catch( final SQLException e )
{
  log.error( "Error querying clients", e );
}
```

And why do you use a prepared statement at all, when you do not have variables in there? Ok, confessed, some RDBMS optimise even those statements, but for fixed-value queries

```
final var statement = connection.createStatement();
final var resultSet = statement.executeQuery( theQueryString );
```

is the more common choice, and it would fit here, too:

```
final var query =
  """
  SELECT contact_phone,
         status, 
         money_spent,
         bonus,
         client_name,
         assigned_employee_number,
         email 
    FROM client 
    WHERE assigned_employee_number IS NULL;""";
List<Client> resultClientList = new ArrayList<>();
try( final var stmt = connection.createStatement() ) 
{
  resultClientList = executeClientQuery( stmt.executeQuery( query ) );
}
catch( final SQLException e )
{
  log.error( "Error querying clients", e );
}
```

Comment: The usage of `executeClientQuery()` is redundant here, [SOLID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) #1.

Comment: @RomanC — the method `executeClientQuery()` is defined by the TO (see the question!!) and it evaluates the `ResultSet` that is provided to it as the parameter. Of course this architecture can be disputed, but you should discuss it with the TO, and not with me!

Comment: I'm discussing it with you because you  sent me your comment. `ResultSet` is provided by the statement, that means the query is already executed. Passing it as a parameter to another method is bugprone, because it's not properly closed.

Comment: @RomanC – You got the comment because you added *your* comment to *my* answer. And there are lots of reasons why the architecture suggested by the TO is problematic, but that the `ResultSet` is not properly closed is none of them – just because it is not true! In both cases (mine and the original one) the statement that is used to generate the `ResultSet` instance is closed, and that in turn also closes the result set. Refer to the respective documentation! May be you should spent some time with real life development and maintenance of software.

Comment: You left unclosed `ResultSet` on promise that a statement which is created somewhere in the code will autoclose it, but you forgot one thing  that resources should be closed as soon as they no longer needed and preferably in the same block of code or a method. Nobody knows where in the code is an object which should close the resource, and until it's not closed you can face a lot of problems begining from resource leaks and ending to a deadlock. The documentation is useless for you because you didn't close `ResultSet` or `Statement` in time and it is a bug.

Comment: @RomanC – Either you have not read the code, or you have no clue what try-with-resources do. Both disqualifies you from continuing this discussion.